# How to navigate from Blazor component (.razor) to .cshtml page?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

In server-side Blazor how can I redirect to .cshtml Login page from Blazor component(.razor)?

**Login.cshtml** (located in the ProjectRoot/Identity/Login folder)

```cs
    @page "/login"
            
    <p> I am login page </p>
```

**Index.razor**

```cs
    @page "/"
    @inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
    
    <AuthorizeView>
        <NotAuthorized>
            @if (true)
            {
                NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
            }
        </NotAuthorized>
    </AuthorizeView>
```

Currently, with the above code, I get an exception: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationException.
What is the proper way of referring to the .cshtml page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom component that triggers a javascript redirect on initialization. Something like this

```cs
[Parameter]
public string Path { get; set; }
[Inject] private IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("BlazorHelpers.RedirectTo", Path);
}
```

Then in your page:

```cs
<AuthorizeView>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <RedirectTo Path="Something"></RedirectTo>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

And your Js would be like this:

```js
window.BlazorHelpers = {       
    RedirectTo: function (path) {
        window.location = path;
    }
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't `OnParametersSetAsync()` be better in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Little late to the party, but I'd recommend just rendering your login component within the `<NotAuthorized>` area. This component could then inject a `NavigationManager` to navigate to your homepage upon successful login.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is generally wondering how to `.NavigateTo()` a Razor page from a Razor component, setting the optional parameter `forceOverload` to `true` should to the job. So it'll look something like this:

`_navigationManager.NavigateTo("/your/uri", true)`

As you can read in the source code `forceOverload` forces loading the actual Razor page, not just the interactive client-side Razor 'component-pages', at least from what I understand.